# Visual Studio Nesting Razor Files

Tags: visual-studio

How can I nest .scss files under .razor files, and .css files under the .scss file in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer?

For example:
.razor
.scss
.css

I've tried creating my own nesting profile to nest files as described above, but I can't seem to get it to work.